# Не отправляется push с TortoiseGit

Tags: git, git-push

Работаю в винде через TortoiseGit. При push-e в Bitbucket появляется ошибка:

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

To https://bitbucket.org/clevermasha/netping
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/clevermasha/netping'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (20390 ms @ 20.02.2014 23:16:49)
```

Что это, как ее исправить?

Comment: сделайте pull сначала.

Comment: > tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart

Ваша локальная ветка отстает от того, что на bitbucket-е. Кто-то другой уже запушил в нее свои изменения и вам, как сказал @eicto, нужно сначала принять их к себе.

Comment: Я сделала pull, всё равно не хочет.

Comment: может pull требует merge ? тут ведь как "не хочет - не ошибка"

Comment: merge тоже делала - то же самое.С помощью fetch удалось загрузить версию коллеги, исправила конфликты, закоммитила, но все равно.

Comment: в общем вот так сделайте (придется из commandline или придумать как это сделать в tortoise)

git checkout master
git checkout -b tmp 
git checkout master
git pull #тут могут быть ошибки, не обращайте внимания, если они не о соединении
git reset --hard origin/master
git merge tmp
git push

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

в общем вот так сделайте (придется из commandline или придумать как это сделать в tortoise):

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b tmp
$ git checkout master
$ git pull #тут могут быть ошибки, не обращайте внимания, если они не о соединении
$ git reset --hard origin/master
$ git merge tmp
$ git push
```

---

от себя добавлю:

временную ветку `tmp` после этих манипуляций можно удалить так:

```
$ git branch -d tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

В TortoiseGit когда будешь делать push просто установи May discard known changes

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]